# Node depth in a random binary search tree

Tags: probability, combinatorics, trees

It can be proved that randomly built binary search trees of size $n$ are of depth $O(\log(n))$ and it is clear that level $k$ has at most $2^{k}$ nodes (root's level is 0).

I have an algorithm that traverses every path in the tree (beginning at the root) but stops after traversing $k$ nodes (the parameter $k$ is a configurable parameter which is independent of the size of the tree $n$).

For any tree $T$ with $depth(T) > k$, the algorithm will miss some nodes of the tree. I would like to bound the probability of my algorithm missing a large number of nodes.

Formalizing it: let $T$ be a randomly built binary search tree of $n$ nodes.  I would like to calculate the probability for a node to have depth larger than $k$, as a function of $n$ and $k$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: What have you tried?